# Understanding rsync behaviour

Tags: rsync

I need to transfer a 100 GB tar file over a Network Connection.

I started the process with 'rsync -avP' to see it's Progress.

Then the Connection broke after a few hours, of Course that was before the process was completed.

I re-run the same command and luckily it seems to just continue the incomplete download.

However, I now read that one should use the --partial Option to enable that behaviour. I didn't use it, but still rsync seems to behave as I want it to - it continues the transfer.

Do I need to cancel and restart, or is everything fine now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rsync -P is [the same as rsync --partial --progress](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) so in supplying -P to get progress you inadvertently got partial too.

So yes, everything is fine now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I mistakenly thought -P would be for "report Progress" ;)